# Change child scope using broadcast from app.run

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, broadcast, angularjs-controller, angularjs-rootscope

I have an angular app with the name DemoProject.

I have an app.run controller and one child controller

JS

```
var app = angular.module("DemoProject", ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages', 'ngMaterial']);

app.run(function ($rootScope, $route, $location, $mdDialog) {
    $rootScope.validate = true;

    $rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', { myName: 'Bala' });

});

app.controller('ChildController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $document, $window) {
    $scope.myName = '';
});
```

I can't update the child controller scope using broadcast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.controller('ChildController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $document, $window) {
  $scope.myName = '';

  $rootScope.$on('eventName', function(event, args){
      console.log(args);
      $scope.myName = args.myName;
  });
});
```

Comment: In the ChildController, I received via args as per your answer. Kindly assist me, how to update the value into the property $scope.myName ?